# Android Profiler: huge memory consumption, tagged as "Others", that doesn't get garbage collected

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, profiler

I wrote a simple app that does three simple things: matches regex, perform OCR and use openCV to preprocess the image for a better OCR result.
For preprocessing the image I am using openCV.
For the OCR I am using Tesseract.
I've noticed that my app gets killed by the OS after 20 minutes or so, so I've tried to launch the Android Profiler and monitor my app activity.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see there is huge memory consumption tagged as "Others" that never goes down. As you can see there is also a relevant consumption tagged as "Native" but that fortunately goes up and down, I guess it depends mainly on when methods of openCV are called.

I have tried the following code:

```
while(true){
Bitmap preprocessedImage = OpenCV.preprocessImageForOCR(imageName);
MyTesseract myTesseract = new MyTesseract(preprocessedImage);
myTesseract.getText();
}
```

and, weirdly enough, the memory consumption is around 200-220 MB (mostly the "Native" code). So, I really don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Most likely the growing other memory part is caused by some code in one of the used native library. The memory profiler has problems to tag all memory allocated by those libraries correctly. Thus the native code most likely has a memory leak or you accumulate data in a structure you are not aware of.

Comment: Is there anyway to find out what exactly is causing this? Could it be because of nested methods that garbage collectors does not clean?
method1() calling inside at a certain point method2(), method 2 calling inside at a certain point method3() and so on...

Comment: Garbage collector only works on Java/Kotlin objects and data. On native level (.so files) there is no garbage collector, thus you have to manually everything you have allocated. If you forget something you have a memory leak.

Comment: But I didn't write native code (C++) myself. I am using openCV that is in C++. Anyway, if that was the case then why I don't get memory leaks by calling in a loop a few Tesseract and openCV methods?

Comment: My only doubt at the moment would be the nested methods. Otherwise I have no clue what the issue could be and no idea how to find out.

Comment: Based on what you have posted this question can not be answered. May be you use multiple threads and that causes the memory somewhere else, or you create a List or Map where you accidentally add data again and again. I would use you original app and then disable step by step smaller code parts until the memory grow is eliminated.

Comment: I just realised you are right. The native code counter after a while gets very low and tagged as "Others".